# Node.js, express, how do I render multiple pages for my website?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server-side-rendering

I have a 100 page website currently served by PHP Apache. I want to convert this website to Node/Express. But does this mean I have to render each page separately, writing this code 100 times for each page?

```js
app.get('/about', (req, res) => res.render('about'))
```

**Thunder** suggested excellent code (see below), but when I made the changes, all the pages could now render, but I would have to add the file extension to the browser address to make the page show. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: You need *some* form of routing, but it doesn't have to be manual. There are many ways it can be implemented.

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters

Answer (score 3):

(I'm not a good explainer but here goes...)

Yes, you can render multiple HTML files with a single function!

You can use `:<parameter name here>` to turn the file name into a parameter, which you can then call from the function with `req.params.<parameter name here>` (aka, Routing). Find more about this here: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters

Because you said you were using PHP Apache, I'll try to provide an individualized solution for you.

Assuming your file directory looks like this:

[image: file directory]

You can use this code in index.js:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const fs = require("fs")
const engines = require('consolidate');
const mustache = require("mustache");

app.set('views', __dirname + "/public_html");
app.engine('html', engines.mustache);
app.set('view engine', 'html');

function checkfile(file) {
    return fs.existsSync("public_html/" + file)
}

app.get('/:filename', (req, res) => {
    try {
        let filestring = req.params.filename.toString()
        if (checkfile(filestring)) {
            res.render(filestring)
        }
        else {
            res.render("404.html")
        }
    } catch {
        res.render("500.html")
    }
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render("index.html")
});

app.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log('server started');
});
```

It will render all files in the `public_html` directory, assuming there are no subdirectories (that would be more complicated).

Example: https://express-multiplefile-test.williamvongphan.repl.co

Comment: Outstanding. Let me get my head around your code and get back to you. Thanks so much, Rick